# eCommerece engine designed to work in UK

Tags: e-commerce

Does anyone know any free (not expensive)/OpenSource eCommerce engines designed to work in UK, i.e. such they use Royal Mail services to calculate shipping costs/delivery time, be able to set up Direct Debit (not crucial though), provide UK credit cards payment facilities, calculate VAT etc.

It should be easily customizable and lightweight, with Web 2.0 features and reach JavaScript.

As a .NET developer with ASP.NET WebForms experience I prefer it to be written in C#, and better in ASP.NET MVC + jQuery so I can modify it if required, but PHP or any other solutions are fine as long as they suite my needs better.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using [Tea Commerce](http://www.teacommerce.dk) for Umbraco. It supports the large british payment gateway Sage Pay. It's very customizable with a solid .NET API and a large eventmodel.

The best thing about it is that it is lightweight and uses JavaScript and ajax to make all requests and posts to the database. This makes it possible to use largely any design.

It's also very inexpensive and is regularly updated with new features. Check out [this demo](http://demo.teacommerce.dk/en/speakers.aspx) where you can see and try a lot of the features.

With the installable Starter Kit or Demo website you will have a working shop up and running in no time.

Also Umbraco is a fantastic CMS. I love building my websites in it, and the next large release of Umbraco will use MVC all the way.

Cheers
Rune